# Accessing data range with h5py

Tags: python, h5py

I have an h5 file that contains 62 different attributes. I would like to access the data range of each one of them.

to explain more here what I'm doing

```
import h5py 
the_file =  h5py.File("myfile.h5","r")
data = the_file["data"]
att = data.keys()
```

the previous code gives me a list of attributes "U","T","H",.....etc

lets say I want to know what is the minimum and maximum value of "U". how can I do that ?

this is the output of running "h5dump -H"

```
HDF5 "myfile.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   GROUP "data" {
      ATTRIBUTE "datafield_names" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 8;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_SPACEPAD;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 62 ) / ( 62 ) }
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "dimensions" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I32BE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4 ) / ( 4 ) }
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "time_variables" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64BE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 2 ) / ( 2 ) }
      }
      DATASET "Temperature" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F64BE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 256, 512, 1024 ) / ( 256, 512, 1024 ) }
      }
```

Comment: What type of object is data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be a difference in terminology, but hdf5 attributes are access via the `attrs` attribute of a Dataset object. I call what you have variables or datasets.  Anyway...

I'm guessing by your description that the attributes are just arrays, you should be able to do the following to get the data for each attribute and then calculate the min and max like any numpy array:

```
attr_data = data["U"][:] # gets a copy of the array
min = attr_data.min()
max = attr_data.max()
```

So if you wanted the min/max of each attribute you can just do a for loop over the attribute names or you could use

```
for attr_name,attr_value in data.items():
    min = attr_value[:].min()
```

**Edit to answer your first comment:**

h5py's objects can be used *like* python dictionaries.  So when you use 'keys()' you are not actually getting data, you are getting the *name* (or key) of that data.  For example, if you run `the_file.keys()` you will get a list of every hdf5 dataset in the root path of that hdf5 file. If you continue along a path you will end up with the dataset that holds the actual binary data.  So for example, you might start with (in an interpreter at first):

```
the_file = h5py.File("myfile.h5","r")
print the_file.keys()
# this will result in a list of keys maybe ["raw_data","meta_data"] or something
print the_file["raw_data"].keys()
# this will result in another list of keys maybe ["temperature","humidity"]
# eventually you'll get to the dataset that actually has the data or attributes you are looking for
# think of this process as going through a directory structure or a path to get to a file (or a dataset/variable in this case)
the_data_var = the_file["raw_data"]["temperature"]
the_data_array = the_data_var[:]

print the_data_var.attrs.keys()
# this will result in a list of attribute names/keys
an_attr_of_the_data = data_var.attrs["measurement_time"][:]

# So now you have "the_data_array" which is a numpy array and "an_attr_of_the_data" which is whatever it happened to be
# you can get the min/max of the data by doing like before
print the_data_array.min()
print the_data_array.max()
```

**Edit 2 - Why do people format their hdf files this way?  It defeats the purpose.**

I think you may have to talk to the person who made this file if possible. If you made it, then you'll be able to answer my questions for yourself.  First, are you sure that in your original example `data.keys()` returned `"U","T",etc.`?  Unless h5py is doing something magical or if you didn't provide all of the output of the h5dump, that could not have been your output.  I'll explain what the h5dump is telling me, but please try to understand what I am doing and not just copy and paste into your terminal.

```
# Get a handle to the "data" Group
data = the_file["data"]
# As you can see from the dump this data group has 3 attributes and 1 dataset
# The name of the attributes are "datafield_names","dimensions","time_variables"
# This should result in a list of those names:
print data.attrs.keys()

# The name of the dataset is "Temperature" and should be the only item in the list returned by:
print data.keys()
```

As you can see from the h5dump, there are 62 `datafield_names` (strings), 4 `dimensions` (32-bit integers, I think), and 2 `time_variables` (64-bit floats).  It also tells me that `Temperature` is a 3-dimensional array, 256 x 512 x 1024 (64-bit floats).  Do you see where I'm getting this information?  Now comes the hard part, you will need to determine how the `datafield_names` match up with the `Temperature` array.  This was done by the person who made the file, so you'll have to figure out what each row/column in the `Temperature` array means.  My first guess would be that each row in the `Temperature` array is one of the `datafield_names`, maybe 2 more for each time?  But this doesn't work since there are too many rows in the array.  Maybe the dimensions fit in there some how?  Lastly here is how you get each of those pieces of information (continuing from before):

```
# Get the temperature array (I can't remember if the 3 sets of colons is required, but try it and if not just use one)
temp_array = data["Temperature"][:,:,:]
# Get all of the datafield_names (list of strings of length 62)
datafields = data.attrs["datafield_names"][:]
# Get all of the dimensions (list of integers of length 4)
dims = data.attrs["dimensions"][:]
# Get all of the time variables (list of floats of length 2)
time_variables = data.attrs["time_variables"]

# If you want the min/max of the entire temperature array this should work:
print temp_array.min()
print temp_array.max()
# If you knew that row 0 of the array had the temperatures you wanted to analyze
# then this would work, but it all depends on how the creator organized the data/file:
print temp_array[0].min()
print temp_array[1].max()
```

I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but without actually having the file and knowing what each field means this is about all I can do.  Try to understand how I used h5py to read the information.  Try to understand how I translated the header information (h5dump output) into information that I could actually use with h5py.  If you know how the data is organized in the array you should be able to do what you want.  Good luck, I'll help more if I can.

Comment: Well accessing the data using the line
        attr_data = data["U"][:]
did not work but I accessed the data using keys()
now when I type att.min() it says 'unicode' object has no attribute 'min'

Comment: I added more to my answer to hopefully explain to you what is going on. Hopefully that helps a little. If you're still confused you could try running "h5dump -H <file>" with a test file and provide us the output. This will help us figure out what exact commands you should run.

Comment: so everything runs fine until the command print the_data_var.attrs.keys() I get an empty array so I tried getting the min and max to the_data_var which supposed to be storing my data for temperature in this example but I get the same previous message, anyway I add to my question the output of running "h5dump -H" to my file

Comment: Edited my answer again, hope this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot davydave400, I'll try to work it and if I have further questions after understanding the data I'll come back

Answer (score 0):

Since h5py arrays are closely related to numpy arrays, you can use the numpy.min and numpy.max functions to do this:

```
maxItem = numpy.max(data['U'][:]) # Find the max of item 'U'
minItem = numpy.min(data['H'][:]) # Find the min of item 'H'
```

Note the ':', it is needed to convert the data to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) (row-wise) on the DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 6], [5, 2], [4, 3]], columns=list('UT'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   U  T
0  1  6
1  5  2
2  4  3

In [3]: df.min(0)
Out[3]: 
U    1
T    2

In [4]: df.max(0)
Out[4]: 
U    5
T    6
```

Comment: What is a dataframe? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Dhara sorry for some reason I read this as a pandas question (I had assumed you were doing [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables)).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `data.attrs` rather than `data` itself? If so,

```
import h5py

with h5py.File("myfile.h5", "w") as the_file:
    dset = the_file.create_dataset('MyDataset', (100, 100), 'i')
    dset.attrs['U'] = (0,1,2,3)
    dset.attrs['T'] = (2,3,4,5)    

with h5py.File("myfile.h5", "r") as the_file:
    data = the_file["MyDataset"]
    print({key:(min(value), max(value)) for key, value in data.attrs.items()})
```

yields

```
{u'U': (0, 3), u'T': (2, 5)}
```